# sqlite sub query delivery strange results

Tags: sqlite

I get unexpected output for the query below.:

```
SELECT *
FROM Ethymologie
WHERE VerbundenesWort IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT VerbundenesWort FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT VerbundenesWort FROM Ethymologie WHERE VerbundenesWort IS         NOT NULL) 
     ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1)
```

I want to choose just one value (in a way which is irrelevant here; using random() for demonstration) from a table ('Ethymologie').
Then I want to list all the rows from the same table which have the same value.
Each of the subqueries works like a charm.

The problematic result only becomes visible when I use the whole sql query.
Here is a screenshot of the strange result.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thx!

Comment: Please provide some lines of `create...` and some lines of `insert...` as a foundation for trying and demonstrating. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please explain what is so strange about the result.

Comment: Please show your schema as the bare minimum of an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the entries with joint-word=1 is what you find strange.
That is caused by the fact that (I have to guess again because of the lack of MCVE, hint hint, or at least a schema, hint hint)
your schema has "joint-word" as text, while you are storing what seems to be indexes into a different table (no design problem in that detail).

So the `IN`operator will find '1' inside '10'.

The actual solution for your problem would hence be to change the column to some kind of integer (possibly foreign key).

But in case you cannot or do not want to,
here is some code to work around your current schema.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Ethymologie 
WHERE VerbundenesWort = 
    (select *
     from 
         (SELECT DISTINCT VerbundenesWort 
         FROM Ethymologie 
         WHERE VerbundenesWort IS NOT NULL
         )
     order by random() limit 1
    );
```

Note that you probably would have the same problem if you stored actually joint words instead of indexes/integer. This is because of the special kind of text, which consists of joint words. Finding 'Donaudampfschiff' in 'Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaft' would also cause the problem.

If you want to be able to make a list of rows with one of several randomly selected words (e.g. `LIMIT 2`), then you have to stick with `IN` but  change schema to int/key, or (ugly workaround) use word boundary delimiters for comparing, which is of course not built into SQLite, but a little magic could do that. But you do not want that kind of magic used for making what is anyway a workaround for a fishy schema, do you? ;-)

Comment: good idea, but the same problem but again ![Valid XHTML](http://imgur.com/a/NLzb2).

Comment: Please, the point of you providing an [mcve] is that other users of StackOverflow do not have to a) invent/guess one b) do not have to type it in. So could you be so nice to edit the information from both of your pictures into your question as **text**? Do not forget to include a few lines of "insert ..." as sample database content.

Comment: You know, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query